# php not getting GET values from url

Tags: php, .htaccess, get

In htacess I have:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/subscribe$ subscribe3.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

My URL is the following:

```
www.mysite.com/es/subscribe?course=1&country=38&t=1
```

PHP is not picking up the variables I have in the URL, any ideas? I tried using & after subscribe but it came up with a 404

Comment: You are not getting the parameters from your URL. The course, country and t parameters will be ignored, as you don't put them in the rewritten URL.

Answer (score 0):

Changing to [L,QSA] worked perfectly